# PowerShell script builds the wrong path in TFS2017

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I am adding a PowerShell script to run in my build to get the Version Number for the build.  When I use the builder(Box with ...) to get the file, it takes me to my TFS Project and I work my way down to the file.  When the build definition runs it fails at that step, because it cant find my script.
What it has done is prepended the local Servers work directory to the front of the Path it had me choose.

I feel this is a Bug or how am I suppose to get the most current copy of a script in TFS when the Build Definition runs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried with a simple powershell script on my side, but couldn't reproduce your issue, the script is working.

Only add one step in build, and map to $/teamproject in Repositity, then select the script:

[image]

To narrow down the issue, you could create a new pipeline with only one task-Powershell, check what will happen.

If you still get error, please share detail logs with `system.debug=true` enable.

Also take a look at this tutorial about how to use powershell fetch/change build number, which may helps-- [Use a PowerShell script to customize your build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops)

---

***Update***

According to your error info, you are lacking of the definition.

Please make sure you have specified the value in options--**build number format**

`$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)`

[image]

Then it should run without any problem:

[image]

Comment: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) 
Build - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) 
Could not find version number with format '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' in BUILD_BUILDNUMBER '573'. At D:\TFSVSOWork\6\s\TECH\PowerShell\AssemblyVersion.ps1:133 char:10 + throw "Could not find version number with format '$VersionFo ... + ~~~ + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (Could not find ...LDNUMBER '573'.:String) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not find version number with format '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' in BUILD_BUILDNUMBER '573 '. 
Process completed with exit code 1 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.

Comment: So I did recreate with just the PS and I received the same issue the D:\TFSVSOWork\6\s shouldn't be there and the Project is missing.  If I remove $ before /Project/TECH I get different results.  But in both cases the I can't run AssemblyVersion.ps1

Comment: @StephanM Sorry for the later reply due to holiday, according to your screenshot, seems you are lacking of the  build number format define. More details please see my update reply, hope it helps. Besides there is a & in the path of script.